# Serving Assets VIA SSL in Rails 3 App Using NGINX and Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, https, asset-pipeline

I have set up my rails app, works great.  Unfortunately on the https:// version of the site, none of my assets are being served... any idea as to why this might happen? All assets get served via http:// but none via https://

Help?

============= CODE ==============

```
upstream unicorn {


server unix:/tmp/unicorn.XXX.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/deployer/apps/XXX/current/public;

location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 5G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
send_timeout 240;
sendfile_max_chunk 5m;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/webuser/apps/XXX/current/public;

location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}

try_files $uri @non-ssl-redirect @unicorn;

location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 5G;
keepalive_timeout 10;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_protocols           SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers             ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;
ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;

send_timeout 240;
sendfile_max_chunk 5m;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your asset host configuration is hard-wired to `http`.  When you view a page over `https`, but load an asset over `http`, many browsers will block the asset or show a warning.

The easiest way to fix this is to set a Rails `asset_host` that does not include a protocol, which should inherit the protocol of the page it's loaded from.

For example:

```
# Use just the asset host domain name for Rails pages
config.action_controller.asset_host = "assets.mycompany.com"
# Specify HTTP for ActionMailer messages, since they don't have a protocol to inherit
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://assets.mycompany.com"
```

If you are properly including your assets with an `https` protocol, but they are failing to load - it's likely there is an SSL certificate name mismatch between the hostname for your assets and the SSL certificate.  For example, if you're serving assets straight from S3 with a custom domain name, the S3 SSL certificate (*.s3.amazonaws.com) will fail to match `assets.yourcompany.com` and cause an SSL error, preventing the assets from loading.

The only fix in this case is to use an asset host or CDN that allows a custom SSL cert to match your hostname, or revert back to the public hostname that matches your providers SSL cert.

Comment: this applies for something like my application.css file as well?

Comment: I added my nginx.conf file (with some omissions) above.